# Dimmer not turn the LED on

Tags: led, dimmer-switch

I have install 2 Lutron 150W(LED) dimmer and connect it to 2 LED recessed light and 6 LED recessed light respectively, all LED light are 5W(6000K) with a driver of it own.

There are few problems after installation:

for the 2 LEDS:

- There is about half second delay when I turn the light on.
- If I turn the dim level to lowest, and turn on the switch, one of them will have difficult to be turned on, but then I can turn the dim level up and all of them will be on.

for the 6 LEDS:

- There is about half second delay when I turn the light on.
- If I turn the dim level to lowest, and turn on the switch, some of them will have difficult to be turned on, but then I can turn the dim level up and all of them will be on.
- If I turn the dim level to highest, none of them will be turned on.

As you can see, they are having the same issue, my contractor told me to purchase higher wattage dimmer. But I am not sure how this will solve the issue.

Please help me :(

Comment: What model number are the LED fixtures/bulbs and the dimmers?

Comment: IME the half-second delay is typical of many LED Dimmers. Irritating, but typical.

Answer (score 1):

IME the half-second delay is typical of many LED Dimmers. It's unlikely that a higher wattage will help, but a different brand might. You already have 150W (I'm hoping you are giving the LED wattage here) connected to 10W and 30W LED respectively. In fact, you may be running into an issue specific the LED dimmers, which is that many of them don't work well without a certain **minimum** wattage connected. I need at least 4 9W fixtures for the dimmers I currently have; on a switch, the LEDs turn on instantly, and on a dimmer they have that annoying delay.

If a contractor, not you, did the job, the contractor should fix it.

The "lowest dimming level" can be adjusted, normally, and should be so that all lamps are on. The highest is also normally adjustable. THose will be covered in the dimmer documentation, as will the issue of a minimum wattage, if that is applicable.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am using Lutron DVCL-153P dimmer